# Analog Keypad (sometimes) returns wrong values

Tags: arduino

I use Arduino UNO plus Analog Keypad. I followed this instructions:
https://arduinogetstarted.com/tutorials/arduino-analog-keypad-library

Now, it all works, except sometimes when I press a button on the keyboard, a wrong value is returned. Looks like an error in Arduino's measuring A0 input (or button sending wrong data).

So if I run the calibration program (see the link), I'll get something like
1020

1020

1020

1020

1020

724

1020

1020

for the same button.

Any suggestions how to fix it?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The library you are using seems to be the following https://github.com/ArduinoGetStarted/Analog-Keypad

Both the calibration code and the  `ezAnalogKeypad::getKey()` function base the keypress on a single `analogRead` call, which is susceptible to errors because you either pressed the key halfway through a read, or one of the electrical connections might not be so great, or maybe your finger wiggled a little while pressing the button.

You could simply call `getKey` multiple times, and only accept a keypress if a majority of the calls return the same value.

The library will actually return `0` if the pressed key is still the same and the second call is within the `debounceTime`.

So you if you have set `debounceTime`, then you could keep calling `getKey` until it returns `0`, and then take the value it returned before that.

something like the following modification to the demo application could work? https://github.com/ArduinoGetStarted/Analog-Keypad/blob/main/examples/AnalogKeypad/AnalogKeypad.ino

```
// modify setup() to set the debounce time to 100 ms
keypad.setDebounceTime(100);


// modify the readKey part in loop() as follows
unsigned char key = 0; // this will contain the key value
unsigned char nextKey = 0;
do
{
  key = nextKey;
  nextKey = keypad.getKey();
} while (nextKey != 0);
if (key)
{
  Serial.println(key);
}
```

You might also be able to get more stable readings by adding a small capacitor between the analog pin and ground, or a bigger capacitor between the ground and supply pins of the keypad.

Comment: Sorry, can not format it...

That is a great idea. Just one question: should I call getKey few times WITHIN debounce period? In other words, in a single pass within loop, like

loop()

{

    getkey

    getkey

    getkey

...

Comment: @SteveBrown i've updated the answer to contain a possible implementation.

Comment: The idea is great. However, code as you provided will run getKey till it isn't zero. It means it can be a nonzero wrong value. So I think I need to read 3-5 times (I'd go for analogRead), bucket (to make sure there is no difference between 900 and 901) and get the value with most frequency.